# SQL concatenate rows query

Tags: mysql, sql

Say we have a table

```
table posts
+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
| postId  | title     | status    | bodyText           |
+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
|   1     | Hello!    | deleted   | A deleted post!    |
|   2     | Hello 2!  | deleted   | Another one!       |
|   3     | New 1     | new       | A new one!         |
|   4     | New 2     | new       | A new one again!   |
```

Can we, in SQL, retrieve a concatenation of a field across rows, by issuing a single query, not having to do the join up in a loop in our back-end code?

Something like

```
select title from posts group by status ;
```

Should give a result like

```
+---------+--------------------+
| deleted | Hello!, Hello 2!   |
| new     | New 1, New 2       |
```

Comment: there's been at least 3 GROUP_CONCAT questions in the last week alone...maybe google is broken.

Comment: Well if I searched for GROUP_CONCAT I'm sure I'd find it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use MySQL then you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT status, GROUP_CONCAT(title)
FROM posts
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: Oh sweet.  This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  status, GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM    posts
GROUP BY
        status
```

In `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  status,
        ARRAY_TO_STRING(
        ARRAY(
        SELECT  title
        FROM    posts pi
        WHERE   pi.status = po.status
        ))
FROM    posts po
GROUP BY
        status
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't indicate a particular SQL engine.

In Firebird (from 2.1) you can use the LIST() function. Take a look at: [link text](http://www.developeando.com/2009/02/firebird-21-list-function.html)

It's an aggregate function to do exactly what you need.

I guess it exists in other engines (LIST in Sybase SQL Anywhere, GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL)