# Combine multiple rows into one space separated string

Tags: sql, mysql, hive

So I have 5 rows like this

```
userid, col
--------------
1, a
1, b
2, c
2, d
3, e
```

How would I do query so it will look like this

```
userid, combined
1, a b
2, c d
3, e
```

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885709/sql-concatenate-rows-query

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
  SELECT yt.userid,
         GROUP_CONCAT(yt.col SEPARATOR ' ') AS combined
    FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
GROUP BY yt.userid
```

The default separator is a comma (","), so you need to specify the SEPARATOR of a single space to get the output you desire.

If you want to ensure the order of the values in the GROUP_CONCAT, use:

```
  SELECT yt.userid,
         GROUP_CONCAT(yt.col ORDER BY yt.col SEPARATOR ' ') AS combined
    FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
GROUP BY yt.userid
```

Comment: I am currently using Hive so I cant do the group by part because GROUP_CONCAT is not recognized as an aggregation function, anyway around it?

Comment: @haoxu: Next option (from a SQL prespective) would be a cursor and string concatenation, but it would require a MySQL function.  I'm not familiar with Hive - is there no way of using a native query?

Comment: Filed a JIRA request for GROUP_CONCAT in HiveQL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1689

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT doesn't actually exist in Hive yet... This solution is only applicable to MySQL.

Comment: Hi i am testing the same on sql lite https://sqliteonline.com/  GROUP_CONCAT is not working

Answer (score 45):

In hive you can use

```
SELECT userid, collect_set(combined) FROM tabel GROUP BY user_id;
```

collect_set removes duplicated. If you need to keep them you can check this post:

[COLLECT_SET() in Hive, keep duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445339/collect-set-in-hive-keep-duplicates)

Comment: exactly what i wanted! works like a charm to concat a row out of a group by query

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  userid,
  concat_ws(" ", collect_set(col)) AS combined
FROM table 
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `MySQL` with duplicates: `select col1, group_concat(col2) from table1 group by col1`
2. `MySQL` without duplicates: `select col1, group_concat(distinct col2) from table1 group by col1`
3. `Hive` with duplicates: `select col1, collect_list(col2) from table1 group by col1`
4. `Hive` without duplicates: `select col1, collect_set(col2) from table1 group by col1`