# COLLECT_SET() in Hive, keep duplicates?

Tags: java, hadoop, user-defined-functions, hive

Is there a way to keep the duplicates in a collected set in Hive, or simulate the sort of aggregate collection that Hive provides using some other method? I want to aggregate all of the items in a column that have the same key into an array, with duplicates.

I.E.:

```
hash_id | num_of_cats
=====================
ad3jkfk            4
ad3jkfk            4
ad3jkfk            2
fkjh43f            1
fkjh43f            8
fkjh43f            8
rjkhd93            7
rjkhd93            4
rjkhd93            7
```

should return:

```
hash_agg | cats_aggregate
===========================
ad3jkfk   Array<int>(4,4,2)
fkjh43f   Array<int>(1,8,8)
rjkhd93   Array<int>(7,4,7)
```

Comment: **If this is not clear**: Please let me know. I'm still trying to solve this :(

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to use COLLECT_LIST(col) after Hive 0.13.0

```
SELECT
    hash_id, COLLECT_LIST(num_of_cats) AS aggr_set
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    blablabla
GROUP BY
    hash_id
;
```

Comment: GROUP BY hash_id
is missing

Comment: the official doc can be found here and explanation on aggregation functions  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)

Answer (score 22):

There is nothing built in, but creating user defined functions, including aggregates, isn't that bad.  The only rough part is trying to make them type generic, but here is a collect example.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.AbstractGenericUDAFResolver;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFEvaluator;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfo;

public class CollectAll extends AbstractGenericUDAFResolver
{
    @Override
    public GenericUDAFEvaluator getEvaluator(TypeInfo[] tis)
            throws SemanticException
    {
        if (tis.length != 1)
        {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(tis.length - 1, "Exactly one argument is expected.");
        }
        if (tis[0].getCategory() != ObjectInspector.Category.PRIMITIVE)
        {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "Only primitive type arguments are accepted but " + tis[0].getTypeName() + " was passed as parameter 1.");
        }
        return new CollectAllEvaluator();
    }

    public static class CollectAllEvaluator extends GenericUDAFEvaluator
    {
        private PrimitiveObjectInspector inputOI;
        private StandardListObjectInspector loi;
        private StandardListObjectInspector internalMergeOI;

        @Override
        public ObjectInspector init(Mode m, ObjectInspector[] parameters)
                throws HiveException
        {
            super.init(m, parameters);
            if (m == Mode.PARTIAL1)
            {
                inputOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) parameters[0];
                return ObjectInspectorFactory
                        .getStandardListObjectInspector((PrimitiveObjectInspector) ObjectInspectorUtils
                        .getStandardObjectInspector(inputOI));
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(parameters[0] instanceof StandardListObjectInspector))
                {
                    inputOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector)  ObjectInspectorUtils
                            .getStandardObjectInspector(parameters[0]);
                    return (StandardListObjectInspector) ObjectInspectorFactory
                            .getStandardListObjectInspector(inputOI);
                }
                else
                {
                    internalMergeOI = (StandardListObjectInspector) parameters[0];
                    inputOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) internalMergeOI.getListElementObjectInspector();
                    loi = (StandardListObjectInspector) ObjectInspectorUtils.getStandardObjectInspector(internalMergeOI);
                    return loi;
                }
            }
        }

        static class ArrayAggregationBuffer implements AggregationBuffer
        {
            ArrayList<Object> container;
        }

        @Override
        public void reset(AggregationBuffer ab)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ((ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab).container = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }

        @Override
        public AggregationBuffer getNewAggregationBuffer()
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer ret = new ArrayAggregationBuffer();
            reset(ret);
            return ret;
        }

        @Override
        public void iterate(AggregationBuffer ab, Object[] parameters)
                throws HiveException
        {
            assert (parameters.length == 1);
            Object p = parameters[0];
            if (p != null)
            {
                ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
                agg.container.add(ObjectInspectorUtils.copyToStandardObject(p, this.inputOI));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object terminatePartial(AggregationBuffer ab)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
            ArrayList<Object> ret = new ArrayList<Object>(agg.container.size());
            ret.addAll(agg.container);
            return ret;
        }

        @Override
        public void merge(AggregationBuffer ab, Object o)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
            ArrayList<Object> partial = (ArrayList<Object>)internalMergeOI.getList(o);
            for(Object i : partial)
            {
                agg.container.add(ObjectInspectorUtils.copyToStandardObject(i, this.inputOI));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object terminate(AggregationBuffer ab)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
            ArrayList<Object> ret = new ArrayList<Object>(agg.container.size());
            ret.addAll(agg.container);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in hive, just issue `add jar Whatever.jar;` and `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect_all AS 'com.example.CollectAll';`
You should them be able to use it as expected.

```
hive> SELECT hash_id, collect_all(num_of_cats) FROM test GROUP BY hash_id;
OK
ad3jkfk [4,4,2]
fkjh43f [1,8,8]
rjkhd93 [7,4,7]
```

It's worth noting that the order of the elements should be considered undefined, so if you intend to use this to feed information into n_grams you might need to expand it a bit to sort the data as needed.

Comment: nice answer :) I ended up trying this and had a few issues. Looking through your code, I see what I did wrong (type-generic *is* hard) and I think this'll work out.

Answer (score 12):

Modified Jeff Mc's code to remove the restriction (presumably inherited from collect_set) that input must be primitive types.  This version can collect structs, maps and arrays as well as primitives.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.AbstractGenericUDAFResolver;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFEvaluator;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfo;

public class CollectAll extends AbstractGenericUDAFResolver
{
    @Override
    public GenericUDAFEvaluator getEvaluator(TypeInfo[] tis)
            throws SemanticException
    {
        if (tis.length != 1)
        {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(tis.length - 1, "Exactly one argument is expected.");
        }
        return new CollectAllEvaluator();
    }

    public static class CollectAllEvaluator extends GenericUDAFEvaluator
    {
        private ObjectInspector inputOI;
        private StandardListObjectInspector loi;
        private StandardListObjectInspector internalMergeOI;

        @Override
        public ObjectInspector init(Mode m, ObjectInspector[] parameters)
                throws HiveException
        {
            super.init(m, parameters);
            if (m == Mode.PARTIAL1)
            {
                inputOI = parameters[0];
                return ObjectInspectorFactory
                        .getStandardListObjectInspector(ObjectInspectorUtils
                        .getStandardObjectInspector(inputOI));
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(parameters[0] instanceof StandardListObjectInspector))
                {
                    inputOI = ObjectInspectorUtils
                            .getStandardObjectInspector(parameters[0]);
                    return (StandardListObjectInspector) ObjectInspectorFactory
                            .getStandardListObjectInspector(inputOI);
                }
                else
                {
                    internalMergeOI = (StandardListObjectInspector) parameters[0];
                    inputOI = internalMergeOI.getListElementObjectInspector();
                    loi = (StandardListObjectInspector) ObjectInspectorUtils.getStandardObjectInspector(internalMergeOI);
                    return loi;
                }
            }
        }

        static class ArrayAggregationBuffer implements AggregationBuffer
        {
            ArrayList<Object> container;
        }

        @Override
        public void reset(AggregationBuffer ab)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ((ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab).container = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }

        @Override
        public AggregationBuffer getNewAggregationBuffer()
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer ret = new ArrayAggregationBuffer();
            reset(ret);
            return ret;
        }

        @Override
        public void iterate(AggregationBuffer ab, Object[] parameters)
                throws HiveException
        {
            assert (parameters.length == 1);
            Object p = parameters[0];
            if (p != null)
            {
                ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
                agg.container.add(ObjectInspectorUtils.copyToStandardObject(p, this.inputOI));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object terminatePartial(AggregationBuffer ab)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
            ArrayList<Object> ret = new ArrayList<Object>(agg.container.size());
            ret.addAll(agg.container);
            return ret;
        }

        @Override
        public void merge(AggregationBuffer ab, Object o)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
            ArrayList<Object> partial = (ArrayList<Object>)internalMergeOI.getList(o);
            for(Object i : partial)
            {
                agg.container.add(ObjectInspectorUtils.copyToStandardObject(i, this.inputOI));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object terminate(AggregationBuffer ab)
                throws HiveException
        {
            ArrayAggregationBuffer agg = (ArrayAggregationBuffer) ab;
            ArrayList<Object> ret = new ArrayList<Object>(agg.container.size());
            ret.addAll(agg.container);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a versioning issue, but I just tried installing into our repo and it compiles but when it gets invoked in hive, it errors with the following: `Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAc
...`

Answer (score 12):

As of hive 0.13, there is a built-in UDAF called `collect_list()` that achieves this. See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions%28UDAF%29).

Comment: Strangely, `collect_list` cannot collect non-primitive types (in Hive 0.13.1).  Otherwise, it would be great to use a built-in function like this.

Comment: the klout team has a GREAT repo of UDFs that you can browse. Among them is a collect function that handles non-primitives. https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/tree/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect

Comment: @jlemaitre, thank you for the link!
"Among them is a collect function that handles non-primitives"
Which one is that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ruslan Its the one called "collect": https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Brickhouse collect UDAF (  http://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java )

It also supports collecting into a map.  Brickhouse also contains many useful UDF's not in the standard Hive distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact hive query that does this job (works only in hive > 0.13):

SELECT hash_id, collect_set( num_of_cats) FROM  GROUP BY hash_id;

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth (though I know this is an older post), [Hive 0.13.0](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions%28UDAF%29) features a new **collect_list()** function that does not deduplicate.

Comment: Could you explain the function a bit? Usually something of this length would be better served as a comment on the answer (which unfortunately you can't do because you don't have enough rep to comment).

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to collect struct

suppose you have a table

```
tableWithStruct(
id string,
obj struct <a:string,b:string>)
```

now create another table as

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename (
id string,
temp array<string>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',' MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

insert query

```
insert into table tablename select id,collect(concat_ws('|',cast(obj.a as string),cast(obj.b as string)) from tableWithStruct group by id;
```

now create another table at same location as **tablename**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename_final (
id string,
array_list array<struct<a:string,b:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',' MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

when you select from **tablename_final** you will get the desired output

Answer (score -1):

Just wondering - if n the statemnent -

```
SELECT
    hash_id, COLLECT_LIST(num_of_cats) AS aggr_set
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    blablabla
GROUP BY
    hash_id
;
```

we want to have sorting and limit the elements for num_of_cats - how to go about it ? COZ in big data we deal with PBs of datas.. we might not need all of that in such cases but top 10 or limit it .

Comment: OK sir - just that I don't have points to add a comment - will try to keep it systematic next time.