# How to get array/bag of elements from Hive group by operator?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I want to group by a given field and get the output with grouped fields. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve:-

Imagine a table named 'sample_table' with two columns as below:-

```
F1  F2
001 111
001 222
001 123
002 222
002 333
003 555
```

I want to write Hive Query that will give the below output:-

```
001 [111, 222, 123]
002 [222, 333]
003 [555]
```

In Pig, this can be very easily achieved by something like this:-

```
grouped_relation = GROUP sample_table BY F1;
```

Can somebody please suggest if there is a simple way to do so in Hive? What I can think of is to write a User Defined Function (UDF) for this but this may be a very time consuming option.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The built in aggregate function `collect_set` ([doumented here](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-BuiltinAggregateFunctions%2528UDAF%2529)) gets you almost what you want. It would actually work on your example input:

```
SELECT F1, collect_set(F2)
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY F1
```

Unfortunately, it also removes duplicate elements and I imagine this isn't your desired behavior. I find it odd that `collect_set` exists, but no version to keep duplicates. [Someone else apparently thought the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445339/collect-set-in-hive-keep-duplicates). It looks like the top and second answer there will give you the UDAF you need.

Comment: In Hive 0.13 there's a `collect_list` function which would return duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

collect_set actually works as expected since a set as per definition is a collection of well defined and **distinct** objects i.e. objects occur exactly once or not at all within a set.