# By using hive query Can I convert table data into complex type list<structure>?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

Here is the table details

```
Id    Data  
a     {"col1":"11.0","col2":30.0}  
a     {"col1":"12.0","col2":10.0}  
b     {"col1":"11.0","col2":20.0}  
b     {"col1":"12.0","col2":25.0}  
b     {"col1":"15.0","col2":25.0}  
c     {"col1":"12.0","col2":15.0}  
c     {"col1":"13.0","col2":16.0}
```

Expected Output - List of Data structures grouped by Id.

```
ID  Data  
a   list[ {"col1":"11.0","col2":30.0},{"col1":"12.0","col2":10.0}]  
b   list[ {"col1":"11.0","col2":20.0},{"col1":"12.0","col2":25.0},{"col1":"15.0","col2":25.0}]  
c   list[ {"col1":"12.0","col2":15.0},{"col1":"13.0","col2":16.0}]
```

Is it possible by functions supported by HIVE or need to write any user define function.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, and there are previous answers to this, see here

[How to get array/bag of elements from Hive group by operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444070/how-to-get-array-bag-of-elements-from-hive-group-by-operator)

But in summary if you you have only unique elements then use collect_set otherwise use collect_list (only works in hive 0.13+), apart from that it is a standard group by query.