# Hive UDF pass array<string> as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to pass in an array to a `Hive UDF` via `collect_set`:

```
SELECT ..., collect_set(...) FROM ...;
```

And my `Hive UDF` wants to take in this array and append the first letter of each array element to an output string:

```
public class MyUDF extends UDF {

public String evaluate(String[] array) {    
    String output = "";

    // Check for valid argument
    if (array == null) return output;

    try {
        // Add first character of every array element to output string
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            output += array[i].charAt(0);

            // If there is another array element after this one, append DELIMITER
            if (i + 1 < array.length) output += ",";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

But the issue I get when I try to run:

```
ADD JAR ./list_builder.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION build_list as 'MyCustomUDF.MyUDF';

SELECT ..., build_list(collect_set(description)) FROM ...;

...
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 142:21 Wrong arguments 'description': No matching method for class MyCustomUDF.MyUDF with (array<string>). Possible choices: _FUNC_(struct<>)
```

I've tried changing `String[]` to `ArrayList` and `List` but I'm still hitting the same error.

**Note**: The output of `collect_set` is something like: `[L-ADD", "P-OAN", "P-OAH"]`, so I'm expecting an output from my UDF like: `L,P,P`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I see no problem with your code. What is the exact input you are giving? I see something like "description" data structure your are trying to pass but that is not acceptable. You might have to do the conversion as necessary.

Comment: You might not need custom UDF for your usecase. Have you tried using substr function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445339/collect-set-in-hive-keep-duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Following @kostya's answer, I used `substr`:

```
SELECT ..., collect_set(substr(description,0,1)) FROM ...;
```

Which meant I didn't need a UDF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]` because hive sends array as `array<String>` not `String[]`

```
public class MyUDF extends UDF {

public String evaluate(ArrayList<String> array) {    

}
```