# detect sequence in hive column with lead function

Tags: hive, lead

I'm trying to detect a sequence in a column of my hive table. I have 3 columns
(id, label, index). Each id has a sequence of labels and index is the ordering of the labels, like

```
id  label   index
a   x   1
a   y   2
a   x   3
a   y   4
b   x   1
b   y   2
b   y   3
b   y   4
b   x   5
b   y   6
```

I want to identify if the label sequence of x,y,x,y occurs.
I was thinking of trying a lead function to accomplish this like:

```
select id, index, label,
lead( label, 1) over (partition by id order by index) as l1_fac,
lead( label, 2) over (partition by id order by index) as l2_fac,
lead( label, 3) over (partition by id order by index) as l3_fac
from mytable
```

yields:

```
id  index  label  l1_fac  l2_fac  l3_fac
a  1  x  y  x  y
a  2  y  x  y  NULL
a  3  x  y  NULL  NULL
a  4  y  NULL  NULL  NULL
b  1  x  y  y  y
b  2  y  y  y  x
b  3  y  y  x  y
b  4  y  x  y  NULL
b  5  x  y  NULL  NULL
```

where l1(2,3) are the next label values. Then I could check for a pattern with

```
where label = l2_fac and l1_fac = l3_fac
```

This will work for id = a, but not id = b where the label sequence is: x, y, y, y, y, x. I don't care that it was 3 y's in a row I am just interested that it went from x to y to x to y.

I'm not sure if this is possible, I was trying a combination of group by and partition, but not successful.

Comment: Do you care *when* the sequence `xyxy` occurs? i.e. at what `index` it occurs?  or do you just want to know that it occured *somewhere* for a given `id`?

Comment: No, I don't care at what index, just that it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324764/hadoop-hive-collect-list-without-repeating-items/31330778#31330778) where the OP wanted to collect items to a list and remove any repeating items.  I think this is essentially what you want to do.  This would extract *actual* `xyxy` sequences and also would account for your second example where `xyxy` occurs, but is clouded by 2 extra `y`s.  You need to collect the `label` column to an array using [this UDAF](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java) -- this will preserve the order -- then use the UDF I referenced, then you can use `concat_ws` to make the contents of this array a string, and lastly, check that string for the occurrence of your desired sequence.  The function `instr` will spit out the location of the first occurrence and zero if it never finds the string.

**Query**:

```
add jar /path/to/jars/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
add jar /path/to/other/jar/duplicates.jar;

create temporary function remove_seq_dups as 'com.something.RemoveSequentialDuplicates';
create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

select id, label_string, instr('xyxy', label_string) str_flg
from (
  select id, concat_ws('', no_dups) label_string
  from (
    select id, remove_seq_dups(label_array) no_dups
    from (
        select id, collect(label) label_array
        from db.table
        group by id ) x
        ) y
     ) z
```

**Output**:

```
id   label_string    str_flg
============================
a    xyxy            1
b    xyxy            1
```

A better alternative might be to simply collect `label` with the UDF, make it a string, and then regex out the sequence `xyxy` but I'm pretty terrible at regex so possibly someone else can comment intelligently on this.

Comment: I was hoping for a non-udf answer, but I will try it.  Thanks.