# Sql subquery with inner join

Tags: sql

I've got these tables in my database:

Tourist - this is the first table

```
    Tourist_ID - primary key
Extra_Charge_ID - foreign key

name...etc...
```

**EXTRA_CHARGES**

```
    Extra_Charge_ID - primmary key 
   Excursion_ID - foreign key

    Extra_Charge_Description
```

**Tourist_Extra_Charges**

```
Tourist_Extra_charge_ID

Extra_Charge_ID - foreign key

Tourist_ID - foreign key
```

**Reservations**

```
Reservation_ID - primary key

.....
```

**Tourist_Reservations**

```
Tourist_Reservation_ID

Reservation_ID - foreign key

Tourist_ID - foreign key
```

So here is my example: I've got reservation with `Reservaton_ID` - 27 
This reservation has two tourists with `Tourist_ID` - 86 and `Tourist_ID` - 87 This Tourist with id 86 has extra charges with `Extra_Charge_ID` - 7 and  and `Extra_charge_ID` - 11;

Is it possible to make sql query and the name and id of the tourist and then all of its 
extra charges

So the output may look like this:

```
Tourist_ID : 86  Name:John   Extra_Charge_ID - 7 Extra_Charge_ID - 11


Tourist_ID: 87  Name:Erika 

Extra-Charge_ID:10
```

(Here is the query I made to get the extra_charge_description of all of the tourists with Reservation_ID = 27 but I don't know how to change it. to get the names above)

```
Select EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID FROM EXTRA_CHARGES

         INNER JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES on EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID

 INNER JOIN TOURIST_RESERVATION on TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = TOURIST_RESERVATION.Tourist_ID
          INNER JOIN  RESERVATIONS on RESERVATIONS.Reservation_ID = TOURIST_RESERVATION.Reservation_ID
          where RESERVATIONS.Reservation_ID=27
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.... You're askingif it is possible to have rows with different formats in a SQL query?

Comment: ... or perhaps improve your query? Is it in tsql?

Comment: The field _Extra_Charge_ID_ should not be in your **Tourist** table: you already link tourists to extra charges via the **Tourist_Extra_Charges** table.

Comment: no it's not in tsql. Yes I want to improve my query so it looks like as I describes above For each tourist - first to get the name and  Id and then all of it's extra_charges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database schema is not completely clear to me, but it seems you can link tourists from the **Tourist** table to their extra charges in the **EXTRA_CHARGES** table via the **Tourist_Extra_Charges** table like this:

```
SELECT  T.Tourist_ID
        ,T.Tourist_Name
        ,EC.Extra_Charge_ID
        ,EC.Extra_Charge_Description
FROM    Tourist AS T
INNER JOIN Tourist_Extra_Charges AS TEC ON T.Tourist_ID= TEC.Tourist_ID
INNER JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES AS EC ON TEC.Extra_Charge_ID = EC.Extra_Charge_ID;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to filter on *Reservation_ID*, you'll have to join the tables **Tourist_Reservations** and **Reservations** as well, like this:

```
SELECT  T.Tourist_ID
        ,T.Tourist_Name
        ,EC.Extra_Charge_ID
        ,EC.Extra_Charge_Description
FROM    Tourist AS T
INNER JOIN Tourist_Extra_Charges AS TEC ON T.Tourist_ID= TEC.Tourist_ID
INNER JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES AS EC ON TEC.Extra_Charge_ID = EC.Extra_Charge_ID
INNER JOIN Tourist_Reservations AS TR ON T.Tourist_ID = TR.Tourist_ID
INNER JOIN Reservations AS R ON TR.Reservation_ID = R.Reservation_ID
WHERE   R.Reservation_ID = 27;
```

As for your database schema: please note that the field *Extra_Charge_ID* is not necessary in your **Tourist** table: you already link tourists to extra charges via the **Tourist_Extra_Charges** table. It can be dangerous to the sanity of your data to make these kind of double connections.

Comment: OF course that Extra_Charge _ID is not in my  table - I wanted it to put EXcursion_ID instead. thank you for your help - I made exactly the same query but now i should think as teh name appears in each row hoe to put only one time the name and then the extra_charges

Comment: Yeah, your original query was just missing the join with the **Tourist** table. It sounds as if you want a result like `7, 11` for the _Extra_Charge_ID_ field in your results, try searching SO for concatenating results into a string (eg [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885709/sql-concatenate-rows-query)) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can have it in delimited list with `GROUP_CONCAT` like:

```
SELECT Tourist_ID, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Extra_Charge_ID SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM Tourist
GROUP BY Tourist_ID
```

Comment: Thanks ! But I've used it with mysql - but now i should make it MS SQL !

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> "This Tourist with id 86 has extra charges with Extra_Charge_ID - 7 and and Extra_charge_ID - 11;"

But your Tourist table does have the Tourist_ID as primary key, so you would not be able to insert the tourist 86 with two different Extra_Charge_ID.

Solution would be to remove the  Extra_Charge_ID from Tourist table.

You already have the Tourist_Extra_Charges, why not use it ?

```
Tourist
-------
86
87
```

and

```
Tourist_Extra_Charges
---------------
1,7,86
2,11,86
```

etc